# Center bootstrap toggle navbar

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

**Hi,

I have struggled all day to make my navbar center on the page without any luck. I have used bootstrap to create the navbar. I would be extremely happy if someone could help me out.** [URL](https://www.cmagelssen.no)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <!-- Required meta tags -->

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-info d-flex justify-content-center">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse h3" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid  bg-info text-white text-center"">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-4">c.magelssen</h1>
    <p class="lead">A resource on psychology, teaching, skiing and coding.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean like this? https://codeply.com/p/7I4qwUCGM9

Comment: do you want to center `toggler` or center your `nav-links`?

Comment: @Codeply-er Yes. What did you do?

Comment: Just use `mx-auto` instead of `mr-auto` .. see the dup question

Comment: @Codeply-er Thank you.